# Python GAE: incoming mail handler error

Tags: python, google-app-engine, email, handler

I'm writing application on GAE that can parse and store incoming mails. I've prepared some simple code for email parsing, but something goes wrong, when I try to simulate e-mail recieveing from admin dev console on local dev server:

```
/develop/google_appengine/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 193, in Handle
    result = handler(self._environ, self._StartResponse)
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
INFO     2012-05-08 16:14:43,516 dev_appserver.py:2891] "POST /_ah/mail/test@example.com HTTP/1.1" 500 -
```

app.yaml:

```
application: mailhandler
version: 1
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

inbound_services:
- mail

handlers:
- url: /_ah/mail/.+ 
  script: email_handler
  login: admin
```

email_handler.py:

```
from google.appengine.ext import webapp 
from google.appengine.ext.webapp.mail_handlers import InboundMailHandler 
from google.appengine.ext.webapp.util import run_wsgi_app
from google.appengine.api import mail

from models import DataStoreManager

class LogSenderHandler(InboundMailHandler):
    # Receiving new mail message and parsing it
    def receive(self, mail_message):                                                                                                                      
        manager = DataStoreManager()
        instance = manager.get_instance_by_email(mail_message.sender.lowercase())

        email_key = manager.store_email(instance, instance.user, mail_message, mail_message.attachments)
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: can you please post the whole traceback?

Answer (score 7):

i think what happens is that in your app.yaml you define the module/file as the script instead of an application, the module is not callable of course.

change the `app.yaml` definition to:

```
handlers:
- url: /_ah/mail/.+ 
  script: email_handler.application
  login: admin
```

and add this line at the end of `email_handler.py`

```
application = webapp2.WSGIApplication([LogSenderHandler.mapping()], debug=True)
```

here the docs:
https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/mail/receivingmail

Answer (score 3):

The problem is you don't have declare a WSGIApplication for your handler `LogSenderHandler`.

You have to read about that on:
https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/python27/using27

```
from google.appengine.ext import webapp 
from google.appengine.ext.webapp.mail_handlers import InboundMailHandler 
from google.appengine.ext.webapp.util import run_wsgi_app
from google.appengine.api import mail

from models import DataStoreManager

class LogSenderHandler(InboundMailHandler):
    # Receiving new mail message and parsing it
    def receive(self, mail_message):                                                                                                                      
        manager = DataStoreManager()
        instance = manager.get_instance_by_email(mail_message.sender.lowercase())

        email_key = manager.store_email(instance, instance.user, mail_message, mail_message.attachments)

application = webapp.WSGIApplication([LogSenderHandler.mapping()], debug=True)
```

After that you have to specify the WSGI application in `your app.yaml`

```
handlers:
- url: /_ah/mail/.+ 
  script: email_handler.application
  login: admin
```

*Note:* As is written in the documentation, the class `InboundMailHandler` has a special method `mapping`  helps you to declare the map of URL.